# Given a pickle dump in python how to I determine the used protocol?

Tags: python, pickle

Assume that I have a pickle dump - either as a file or just as a string - how can I determine the protocol that was used to create the pickle dump automatically?

And if so, do I need to read the entire dump to figure out the protocol or can this be achieved in O(1)? By O(1) I think about some header information at the beginning of the pickle string or file whose read out does not require processing the whole dump.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I have an update on this, apparently the answer given below does not always work under python 3.4. If I simply pickle the value `True` with protocol 1, sometimes I can only recover protocol 0 :-/

Comment: Beware that there is no integrity or validity constraints, and you cannot check wether string is valid pickle dump besides by unpickling. That has some consequences: for example buffer object is pickable but resulting string is unpickable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find out / print with which version of the protocol a pickle file has been generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53431125/how-can-i-find-out-print-with-which-version-of-the-protocol-a-pickle-file-has)

Answer (score 5):

You could roll your own using `picketools`:

```
with open('your_pickle_file', 'rb') as fin:
    op, fst, snd = next(pickletools.genops(fin))
    proto = op.proto
```

It appears that a PROTO marker is only written as the first element where the protocol is 2 or greater. Otherwise, the first element is a marker or element that indicates if the protocol is 0 or 1.

Update into kludging even more land:

```
pops = pickletools.genops(pickle_source)
proto = 2 if next(pops)[0].proto == 2 else int(any(op.proto for op, fst, snd in pops))
```

Comment: that wont destinguish between `protocol=0` and `protocol=1`

Comment: @alko I think it does... Do you have a specific case it doesn't?

Comment: yep, any will do `op, fst, snd = next(pickletools.genops(cPickle.dumps('123', protocol=0)))` followed by `{'MARK': 0,'PROTO': fst}.get(op.name, 1)`

Comment: @alko Thanks... I completely omitted a simple test... (I was trying more complicated data structures)... I think the new approach now works... Although I'm happy to make any changes if not...

Comment: Thanks, seems to work now! How costly is the `genops` operation? Does that require to process the whole pickle dump? I guess not since it returns an iterator (generator?). However, how can I be sure that the first iterator item contains the correct protocol? Don't I need to check all opcodes and use all items of the iterator?

Comment: @SmCaterpillar from my (albeit quick) reading of the source code, the whole pickle thing is a simple 1) load a byte to determine what to do next, 2) do that thing, 3) repeat... So the above code doesn't require loading the entire file. Since 2 is the only proto that puts a proto header in and puts it first, that's fine. In terms of 0 and 1, they can't be mixed in the same pickle (I think...) so just taking the proto of any element present in the pickle should be sufficient...

Comment: It seems like the code is not working for all objects. It breaks for the numpy array `np.array([1,2,3])`, for instance.

For complex objects it seems like I have to go through all `genops` and take the maximum of all `op.proto` :-(

Comment: @SmCaterpillar I thought this might be a bit of a rabbit hole :) Anyway, I'm sure a proto of 2 is first if it's proto of 2. Otherwise, instead of taking the max, you can short circuit in the case it's got a proto of 1 (added to answer). Which means only proto 0 requires a full scan. Failing that, I couldn't find any documentation on an easy way, so maybe hacking the `Pickle.load` function ... which gives me another idea...

Comment: @SmCaterpillar https://bitbucket.org/python_mirrors/cpython-fullhistory/src/85a34a316969278593d454a86ef43a2f76c2d76c/Lib/pickletools.py?at=default has lots of info... and it appears that a pickle having a protocol version is only a protocol 2 thing. So, until that version, the only way to check if it's a protocol 0, is to make sure it's not a protocol 1... Which is now pretty much what this answer does... (yuck)

Comment: I have an update on this, apparently that does not always work under python 3.4. If I simply pickle the value ``True`` with protocol 1, sometimes I can only recover protocol 0 :/

Comment: I got an `ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3` error so I wrote a code to translate it to protocol 2 but strangely when I use 

```with open('your_pickle_file', 'rb') as fin:
    op, fst, snd = next(pickletools.genops(fin))
    proto = op.proto```

to know whether the file can be skipped, proto = 2 when the protocol is actually 3 according to the error above.

Answer (score 4):

**2020 update**:

I tried the methods here (from @JonClements's answer and from the comments), but none seemed to give me the correct protocol.

The following works, however:

```
proto = None
op, fst, snd = next(pickletools.genops(data))
if op.name == 'PROTO':
    proto = fst
```

Alternative (not cool, as it unpickles the whole thing):

```
out = io.StringIO()
pickletools.dis(data, out)
firstline = out.getvalue().splitlines()[0]
if ' PROTO ' in firstline:
    proto = re.sub(r'.*\s+', '', firstline)
    proto = int(proto)
```

Application: I want to find out what pickle protocol has been used in a `pandas.to_hdf()` (if pickling has been used, which is not always the case) and, since I don't fancy analyzing the whole structure of the HDF5 file, I am using a [`MonkeyPatch`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch) to spy on what `pickle.loads()` is asked to deserialize.

Whoever lands here via a Google search, here is my whole (kludgy) setup:

```
__pickle_loads = pickle.loads


def mock_pickle_loads(data):
    global max_proto_found
    op, fst, snd = next(pickletools.genops(data))
    if op.name == 'PROTO':
        proto = fst
        max_proto_found = max(max_proto_found, proto)
    return __pickle_loads(data)


def max_pklproto_hdf(hdf_filename):
    global max_proto_found
    max_proto_found = -1
    with MonkeyPatch().context() as m:
        m.setattr(pickle, 'loads', mock_pickle_loads)
        try:
            pd.read_hdf(hdf_filename)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return max_proto_found
```