# How can I find out / print with which version of the protocol a pickle file has been generated

Tags: python, pickle

In some cases, when I load an existing pickle file, and after that dump it again, the size is almost halved.

I wonder why, and the first suspect is the protocol version.
Can I somehow find out with which protocol version a file was pickled?

Comment: The protocol version of the pickle is detected automatically, so no protocol argument is needed. Bytes past the pickled object’s representation are ignored.
source: [link](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pickle.html#pickle.load)

Comment: Indeed it is detected automatically. Still I'd like to know it, to find out if the factor 2 "shrink" is due to the protocol version or to information loss by some error in my application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way but to get down to the metal you can use `pickletools`:

```
import pickle
import pickletools
s = pickle.dumps('Test')
proto_op = next(pickletools.genops(s))
assert proto_op[0].name == 'PROTO'
proto_ver = proto_op[1]
```

To figure out the version required to decode this, you'll need to maximum protocol version of each opcode:

```
proto_ver = max(op[0].proto for op in pickletools.genops(s))
```

Comment: That helps me out!

Answer (score 1):

A convenient solution in command line by using `pickletools`:

```bash
$ python -m pickletools filename.pickle
    0: \x80 PROTO      5
    2: \x95 FRAME      14451
   11: ]    EMPTY_LIST
   12: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 0)
   ...
14459: b    BUILD
14460: a    APPEND
14461: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 5
```

The first line with `PROTO` showing the pickle Protocol version of the file. And the last line also give you infomation abouth the protocol.